# Merge rows by duplicate columns in awk/unix with condition

Tags: shell, awk, sed

How can we used awk/sed/unix command to massage the data. I have a data as below:

```
/abc/def1.0/Acc101 500 50
/abc/def1.0/Acc101 401 27
/abc/def1.0/Acc101 200 101
/abc/def1.0/Acc201 200 4
/abc/def1.0/Acc301 304 2
/abc/def1.0/Acc401 200 204
```

For each unique string in the first column $1 how can we merge the value which is separated by value. Column $2 is the code if its 200 it means success other then that its Failed. $3 is the count of the occurrence.

Below are the sample output as we distinct $1 and validate value which has either value 200 or not 200 in $2 and merge/sum the count in $3. Sample as below:

```
/abc/def1.0/Acc101 101 77
/abc/def1.0/Acc201 4 0
/abc/def1.0/Acc301 0 2
/abc/def1.0/Acc401 204 0
```

Info for the line: 
/abc/def1.0/Acc101 101 77

77 = sum of 50+27 from $3 which the value of $2 != 200

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
awk '{ groups[$1] = 1; if ($2 == 200) succ[$1] += $3; else fail[$1] += $3 }
     END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
           for (g in groups) print g, succ[g]+0, fail[g]+0 }' input.txt
/abc/def1.0/Acc101 101 77
/abc/def1.0/Acc201 4 0
/abc/def1.0/Acc301 0 2
/abc/def1.0/Acc401 204 0
```

If using GNU awk, the `PROCINFO` line will result in sorted output, otherwise the order is arbitrary and if you want it sorted, can be piped to `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the Input_file 2 times for easiness and could try following once.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  mainarray[$1]
  if($2!=200){
    sum[$1]+=$NF
  }
  if($2==200){
    Found200[$1]+=$NF
  }
  next
}
($1 in mainarray) && !($1 in Found200){
  print $1,0,sum[$1]!=""?sum[$1]:0
  next
}
$2==200{
  print $1,Found200[$1]!=""?Found200[$1]:0,sum[$1]!=""?sum[$1]:0
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed information for above.

```
awk '                                                           ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                                        ##FNR==NR condition will be TRUE when first time Input_file will be read.
  mainarray[$1]                                                 ##Creating array with index $1 here.
  if($2!=200){                                                  ##Creating array named sumwith index $1 and keep adding last column value in it.
    sum[$1]+=$NF                                                ##Creating array named sumwith index $1 and keep adding last column value in it
  }
  if($2==200){                                                  ##Checking condition if 2nd field is equal to 200 then do following.
    Found200[$1]+=$NF                                           ##Creating array Found200 with index #1and keep adding last column value to its value.
  }
  next                                                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in mainarray) && !($1 in Found200){                         ##Checking condition if $1 is present in mainarray and $1 is NOT present in Found200 array.
  print $1,0,sum[$1]!=""?sum[$1]:0                              ##Printing first field, zero and value of sum with $1 here.
  next                                                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
$2==200{                                                        ##Checking condition if 3rd field is 200 then do following.
  print $1,$NF!=""?Found200[$1]:0,sum[$1]!=""?sum[$1]:0         ##Printing first field, Found200 vaue with sum value.
}
' Input_file  Input_file                                      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```